# Can I narrow results from Elastic Search _stats get?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-indices

I am using elastic search for the project I'm working on and I was wondering if there was a way to narrow the results I get from an indices stats search.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-stats.html

I currently use the `docs` to narrow the data I get back about the indices but now I want to only get back ones with a doc count greater than 0. Does anyone know if this is possible or how to?

Thanks!

For elastic search 1.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're concerned about the size of the response (i.e. if you many many indices with many shards), the best you can do is to use [response filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#_response_filtering) (available only since ES 1.7) and only retrieve the `docs` field that you can further filter on the client-side:

```
curl 'localhost:9200/_stats/docs?pretty&filter_path=**.docs.count'
```

Comment: I just learned we are using elastic search 1.5.2 so this won't work. :(

Comment: Ouch, bad luck. Then I guess you're left with filtering the response on the client-side, but if you don't have thousands of indices/shards, that should be ok.